# MemoryMappedViewAccessor performance workaround

Tags: c#, dispose, memory-mapped-files, unsafe

Context for avoiding XY-Problem:

I have a program that uses read-only memory mapped files via `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile` and `CreateViewAccessor` to read binary data. Reading was *supposed* to work via `ReadUInt32`, `ReadUInt16`, `ReadByte` and `ReadArray` on the `MemoryMappedViewAccessor`, but this turns out to be extremely slow. As best as I can tell, the `Read*` functions acquire the underlying pointer to the memory separately for every read.
Acquiring the pointer also involves synchronization, so using multiple threads/tasks to access the file actually slows the accesses down.

I have rewritten the class to acquire the pointer to the memory via `SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer` in the constructor, and attempted to implement correct cleanup via the `IDisposable` interface. Unfortunately, the `Read*` functions for types greater than `byte` may require unaligned accesses. On x86, `*(UInt32*)(pointer)` works, but this is obviously not portable or safe.

1) Is the following use of the `IDisposable` interface correct?

2) How can I correctly and portably do unaligned reads from the memory mapped file?

or 3) Is there a way to reduce the overhead of the `MemoryMappedViewAccessor.Read*` functions for explicitly read-only mappings?

```
public unsafe class MyReader : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly MemoryMappedFile mmf;
        private readonly MemoryMappedViewAccessor mma;
        private readonly byte* pointer;
        private bool disposed = false;

        public MyReader (string filename)
        {
            mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (filename, FileMode.Open, filename, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
            mma = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
            mma.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer (ref pointer);
        }

        private UInt32 ExampleReadAccess (long pos)
        {
            //return mma.ReadUInt32 (pos); //Way too slow, at least 2x slower than the following
            return *(UInt32*)(pointer + pos);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed) return;
            mma.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
            if (disposing)
            {
                mma.Dispose();
                mmf.Dispose();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }

        ~MyReader()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: It took quite a while before support for MMFs was added to .NET.   You found out why.  If it needs to be as fast as possible then you must use pointers.  Why it needs to be unaligned is quite unclear, that problem started somewhere else.

Comment: @HansPassant I need unaligned access because the file format has variably-sized fields, and no padding is inserted to align the fixed-size fields. I *could* read the bytes into an array and use `BitConverter`, but performance is pretty bad already.

Comment: That is another very traditional mistake.  This data needs to come off a disk somewhere.  You are not measuring the cost of retrieving it when you run your test code over and over again.  It comes from the file system cache, just a memory-to-memory copy.  There because you read the file before.  That doesn't happen in Real Life very often.

Comment: @HansPassant It does in this case, because I can keep using the open file for multiple accesses.

Comment: By far the best way to make data available for multiple accesses is by storing it in a plain C# variable.   You don't pay for the cost of having to convert it over and over again.

Comment: @HansPassant The file has a variable size, which can be quite large. I've never done binary file deserialization in C# before, and was unaware that C# memory mapped file performance is so atrocious. Had I known, I might have designed this differently, but I would still like to avoid deserializing multiple gigabytes if possible. As far as I understand, the MMF will degrade gracefully by demand-paging. Anyway, an answer to the first two points (correctness of the `Dispose()` and an unaligned read) would be sufficient for me to accept an answer.

Comment: @Evk If `pointer + pos` refers to a memory address that is not a multiple of the size of `UInt32`, loading a `UInt32` from it will fault on a lot of computer architectures, and produce weird results on a few others.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I think what you need is Unsafe.ReadUnaligned method. Unsafe class is in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe nuget package.

Comment: And if you are interested what `Unsafe.ReadUnaligned` does - it does the same `*(UInt32*)` cast, but before that it uses `unaligned` IL instuction - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unaligned(v=vs.110).aspx